# SignFile task failed - Contains a virus or unwanted software?

Tags: c#, clickonce, publish, publishing, virus

I've been working on an update to an application which generates the interface on the go in some areas to make adding additional features more streamline and have gone to publish it.. but am now getting thrown an error

> The SignFile task failed unexpectedly - Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

Is there anyway to find out which file it is referring too or what is possibly causing this error to be thrown?

I have tried downgrading nugets to versions before I upgraded them and have had no success.

[image: Error Thrown]

Comment: Everything I read thinks you actually do have malware on your computer.  Have you tried turning everything off in the way of Virus checking, before compiling?

Comment: Turns out this was the solution ^, after checking my virus vault it turns out that setup.exe was being removed during the publish process - Would you like to submit this as an answer so I can give you the credit?

Comment: Glad that worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I read thinks you actually do have malware on your computer. Have you tried turning everything off in the way of Virus checking, before compiling?